# KinectJS - Can't remove my shape

Tags: kineticjs

I'm using KinectJS to create my own little drawing program. Everything is going great - until he have to remove my shapes from my stage/layer.

I've used:

```
        layer.removeChildren();
```

Which removes everything. That's a little to much for my little project :-(
I'm drawing multiple shapes on one layer. I need to target only one of my shapes and remove it.

This is how I "try" to remove my target shape, before redrawing it:

```
 function drawElement(figureId) {
        figureId = Number(figureId);

        var figureOld = layer.get("#figure" + figureId)[0];

        layer.remove(figureOld);

        //I Get the shape!
        console.log(figureOld);

        var fillColor = "blue";
        var strokeColor = "red";

        var targetedFigure = figuresArray[figureId];

        var userElement = new Kinetic.Shape({
            drawFunc: function (canvas) {
                var context = canvas.getContext();
                context.beginPath()
                $.each(targetedFigure.coords, function (i, item) {
                    context.lineTo(item.x, item.y);
                });
                context.closePath();
                canvas.fillStroke(this);
            },
            fill: fillColor,
            stroke: strokeColor,
            strokeWidth: 1,
            id: "figure" + figureId,
        });

        layer.add(userElement);
        stage.add(layer);
}
```

Thank you for your time :-)

Update, changed:

```
layer.remove(figureOld);
```

To

```
if (figureOld) {
   figureOld.remove();
}
```

- Thank you MARK!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove any specific shape like this: figureOld.remove();